# can't open my drive with Ubuntu where Windows were located

Tags: ssd

I'm new to using Ubuntu and I downloaded it to recover my files, after I was unable to repair the Windows 0xc000000f error. The problem is that I am able to access the HDD disk from Ubuntu, but it doesn't show the SSD disk, where Windows is located. I've tried using the newest version 20.04 and an older 16.04 and both of them wouldn't show me the SSD disk.

Comment: This is not a good idea to use Ubuntu for this purpose. Most likely the SSD is dead.

Comment: I was able to access some files from the SSD by opening the notepad from the command prompt, but not the most important ones, so does this still mean that there are SSD problems?

Comment: Also a youtube video suggested using Ubuntu

Comment: It seems there is hope, but some files might be damaged. Did you open notepad from Windows or Ubuntu? Can you boot into Windows now? If the NTFS file system is damaged, it is best to repair it with Windows tools, for example **make a Windows PE system in a USB drive, boot from it and try to repair the file system**. It is also possible to use Ubuntu, but if you never used it before, there is a learning curve, and **you probably need a dialogue, that it easier to maintain at [the Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org)**. AskUbuntu is a question & answer site, not suitable for a long dialogue.

Comment: So I managed to fix it after reinstalling windows, turns out it wasn't a problem with the SSD, but most likely a corrupted file. Thank you for the help!